# Matching two enumerations of strings in a LINQ-query

Tags: linq, string, list, match

I have 3 classes (simplified for this question):

```
public class Page
{
    public Guid PageUid;
    public string PageTitle;
    public IQueryable<Keyword> Keywords;
}

public class News
    public Guid NewsUid;
    public string NewsTitle;
    public IQueryable<Keyword> Keywords;
}

public class Keyword
    public Guid KeywordUid;
    public string KeywordTitle;
}
```

I want to list all news-entries on a page where all (not any) keywords of this page matches with some or all of the keywords of the news. The page should display only news, where all the keywords of the page are present in the news. If one of the keywords of the page is not present in a news, this entry should not be displayed. But if the news-entry has more keywords than the page, the news should be displayed – if the keywords of the page are also present in the list of keywords of this news-item. If not, than the news should of course not be listed.

Quite complicated to explain, i try to sketch a real-life-example for better understanding:

**Example:**

The definitions are:

```
- PageA has 1 keyword:  Kw1
- PageB has 2 keywords: Kw1, Kw2
- PageC has 2 keywords: Kw1,      Kw3
- PageD has 3 keywords: Kw1, Kw2, Kw3

- NewsW has 1 keyword:  Kw1
- NewsX has 2 keywords: Kw1, Kw2
- NewsY has 2 keywords: Kw1,      Kw3
- NewsZ has 3 keywords: Kw1, Kw2,      Kw4
```

The results should be:

```
- PageA displays 4 items:       NewsW, NewsX, NewsY, NewsZ
- PageB lists 2 news:                  NewsX,        NewsZ
- PageC shows only 1 entry:                   NewsY
- PageD has not even one match.
```

The 'linking' element is the string 'KeywordTitle' and not the Guid 'KeywordGuid' or just the 'Keyword'-object, because keywords should match if just the title (string) is identical.

In reality the 3 classes are tables in a database. I connect to the database with EntityFramework. The language is C#. The project is a ASP.NET MVC 3 Website.

The solution for my problem should be a LINQ-query if possible.

I hope someone has a solution for this – i tried so many different things, but had no success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

DanielD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<News> news = …;
Page page = …;
var newsOnPage = news.Where(n => page.Keywords.All(pk => n.Keywords.Contains(pk)));
```

This assumes comparing keywords by the default comparer works as expected.

Comment: This works for the upper example in case of PageA, PageB, PageC. PageD unfortunately shows news-entries although it should not because these 3 keywords Kw1, Kw2, Kw3 are not present in any of the news together.

Comment: Ok, @svick, it seems you are right. Mea culpa! This was my fault.

But I tried it in my a little bit more complicated real code and there was an option in my following code to show some news although no news-keywords match to prevent showing empty news-pages.

Sadly there has rised another problem: I simplyfied my first code-example a little bit too much, I updated it now. The new  problem is, that there are no Lists<> of 'KeywordTitles' in the Page and News classes. I have an enumeration<> of linked 'Keywords' and have to match the 'KeywordTitle' of these objects. 

Now I get an LINQ-error.

Comment: This is my final approach and works like a charm - in just one line of code: `var NewsOnPage = News.Where(n => Page.Keywords.Select(t => t.Title).All(pk => n.Keywords.Select(k => k.Title).Contains(pk)));` Thank you, @svick.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of news keywords and page keywords must result in all page keywords. All page keywords must appear in news keywords. I had a similar situation and here is how I did it.

```
if (ANews.Keywords.Intersect(APage.Keywords).Count() == APage.Keywords.Count())
{
     // Display news.
}
```

Comment: I need a query-result like svick suggested in his post. 'If' will not work, because I have many news and not only one. So I can't write 'ANews.Keywords...' because ANews is an enumeration of elements.